# DotNetNuke HouseMenu Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm new to DotNetNuke, I want to know how to add menu in Housemenu module and how to customize its layout. Where can I find the css used for this module? Or if you can give me a link of FREE tutorial in using Housemenu that would be very cool. I've already searched for tutorials but there's only one tutorial that I found but it needs payment. :(

Thank you and your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure HouseMenu module doesn't work with DotNetNuke 6, but you can find the information about the module at houseofnuke.com.

I would recommend using the DDRMenu or the DNNNav menu within DotNetNuke 6. I have an example skin at http://multifunction.codeplex.com that uses the DNNNav menu in a DNN6 skin.